# xCharts - Rendering of text is blurry

Tags: d3.js

I am testing out xCharts which uses the d3.js library (http://tenxer.github.com/xcharts), however when I attempt to render the chart on my website and on jsfiddle the text is blurry.  You can see how it looks different below.

http://jsfiddle.net/JsPxx/

This is the code I am using.

```
 (function () {

      var data = {
  "xScale": "ordinal",
  "yScale": "linear",
  "main": [
    {
      "className": ".pizza",
      "data": [
        {
          "x": "Pepperoni",
          "y": 4
        },
        {
          "x": "Cheese",
          "y": 8
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
      var myChart = new xChart('bar', data, '#myChart');

    }());
```

Any help on why it does not look the way it should (as on http://tenxer.github.com/xcharts) would be appreciated/

Comment: Hey, how'd that work out?

Comment: Meetamit, thank you it worked well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The tick lines of the axis are getting anti-aliased, so they appear as two pixels wide. By adding `shape-rendering:crispEdges` to the CSS class of the axis – or to the whole chart, if you'd like – you can disable anti-aliasing.
   You can read more about it in this [great tutorial](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes/) by Scott Murray.
2. The text seems to have a stroke applied to it (it may be coming from your code or from your css, or from defaults). Giving it CSS `stroke: none` is one way to take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

in xchart.css find `.xchart .axis text` selector and add `stroke-width: 0;` rule